# Facing issue when sdk version is updated in Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, intercom

I am using intercom sdk version 3.+ for notification purpose. I need to update the intercom sdk version to 5.+. After updating the sdk version in gradle file I faced the below error.

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name (at \u0027textAppearance\u0027 with value \u0027@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification\u0027).","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\Android-2\.android\build-cache\971cf0b344c5894d7c756a8e5b80dd3e25a942ef\output\res\layout\activity_add_source.xml","position":{"startLine":32,"startColumn":40,"startOffset":1209,"endColumn":84,"endOffset":1253}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
>   C:\Users\Android
>   2\Desktop\Files\OriginalCode\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_add_source.xml:28: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textAppearance' with value '@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification').
>   :app:processDebugResources FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

I also checked in different ways to resolve the above issue. But I can't. If I created a new project in android studio and checked with intercom sdk version 5.+. It accepts and no issues. I faced only in my existing app. Kindly help me on this issue.

activity_add_source.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <com.stripe.android.view.CardMultilineWidget
            android:id="@+id/add_source_card_entry_widget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/add_card_total_margin"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/add_source_error_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/add_source_card_entry_widget"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_add_source_error"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/add_card_total_margin"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you post your activity_add_source.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding the following style in your styles.xml

`<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ccc</item>
</style>`

NB: Change text and color as per your preferences